# Mapping degree mod $2$

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a closed smooth manifold, let $N$ be a conncected smooth manifold with boundary (perhaps $\partial N = \emptyset$), and let $f:M\to N$ be a smooth map.

It is known that the number mod $2$ of points in a non-empty regular level set of $f$ does not depend on the choice of the regular value. (This number in $\mathbb{Z}/2$ is called the *mapping degree mod $2$* of $f$.)
Is this also true if the regular level set is empty?
I mean: Can it happen that $f$ has two regular values $y,y'\in N$ such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is empty but $f^{-1}(y')$ contains an odd number of points?

I do not find a counterexample but I do not know either how to prove that this cannot occur.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is $0$ equal to an odd number mod $2$?

Comment: No, but this is the point of my question. If there existed a smooth map $f:M\to N$ with an empty regular level set and a regular level set with an odd number of points, then its mapping degree mod $2$ in the above sense would *not* be well-defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever proof you read that $|f^{-1}(y)| \pmod 2$ is independent of the choice of regular value $y$ does not use the assumption that this set is nonempty.

One standard argument: you found a path $\gamma$ running between two regular values $y, y'$ so that $f$ is transverse to $\gamma$, and took the preimage $f^{-1}(\gamma)$. (Pick an arbitrary path and wiggle it to make it transverse.)

Then $f^{-1}(\gamma)$ is a compact 1-manifold with boundary $f^{-1}(y) \sqcup f^{-1}(y')$, and a compact 1-manifold has an even number of boundary points.

This argument does not use the assumption that $f^{-1}(y)$ is nonempty.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know this argument.